# $mail->send() in PHPMailer is returning true but I didn't receive mail

Tags: php, phpmailer

I'm using PHPMailer to send emails from my website but `$mail->send()` is returning true and mail is not sending. No error is reporting in my error log. I hosted my site in Bigrock. I didn't find any errors in my code.

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    require 'class.smtp.php';
    require 'PHPMailerAutoload.php';
    ini_set('SMTP','localhost' ); 
    ini_set('sendmail_from', 'exmaple@gmail.com');
    $fromrec=$_POST['from'];
    $from="example@gmail.com";
    $subject=$_POST['sf'];
    $message=$_POST['message'];
    $mail = new PHPMailer;
    $mail->IsSMTP();
    $mail->Host = "localhost";
    $mail->setFrom($from, 'Rahul');
    $mail->addAddress("example1@gmail.com");
    $mail->Subject  = $subject;
    $mail->Body     = "From:".$fromrec."".$message;
    if(!$mail->send()) {
        echo 'Message was not sent.';
        echo 'Mailer error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
    } else if($mail->send()) {
        echo 'Message has been sent.';
        echo  $mail->ErrorInfo;
    }
    else
    {
        echo 'Mailer error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: mail cannot be sent from localhost.

Comment: I hosted my site in Bigrock can I give my host address?

Comment: yes try with it, or you can check with google smtp settings

Comment: yes, I have modified that with my domain name "http://example.com" and I got this error: SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting

Comment: there are some settings to allow mail to send from the server in bigrock or godaddy which needs to be configured, you need to configure them first then it will work according to your hostname

Comment: I can't find any settings in bigrock and I don't know much about it please guide me

Comment: https://manage.bigrock.in/kb/servlet/KBServlet/faq1311.html,https://support.bigrock.com/index.php?/Knowledgebase/Article/View/873/9/using-a-php-email-script try to go through this 2 sites and follow the steps

Comment: I have already refer those articles, I didn't find any useful information

Comment: https://support.bigrock.com/index.php?/Knowledgebase/Article/View/873/9/using-a-php-email-script go through this once

Answer (score 0):

On this issue, I have consulted Bigrock customer care and I made a chat with them. It's simple in the above code the from address email id must be domain specific and to address would be anything. After changing the email id to domain specific and Host to mail.example.com. My problem has been solved. If anyone got the same problem please try this.